# how to use crontab to run a Graphical program such as "gedit"

Tags: cron

how to use crontab to run a Graphical program such as "gedit"

```
57 12 * * * gedit --display=localhost:0
```

Can not successfully open the program and display it.

Comment: done,crontab should be like this;

    `15 13 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && gedit`

Comment: I'm very curious to know the use case :D

Answer (score 3):

`--display=localhost:0` can be causing error ,

Following code will also do the trick

```
 57 12 * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /usr/bin/gedit
```

There is a reason why i added entire path of gedit ,

Utilities in `/bin` and `/usr/bin` can be opened using cron just by specifying its name so 
`/usr/bin/gedit` or just `gedit` will work.
May a time command you use to start certain utility on terminal doesn't work using cron ,this is because cron passes a minimal set of environment variables to your jobs.May be required env PATH variable is not available with Cron hence it is not able to locate that utility.

you can find a detailed explanation in first reply [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/23438/).

Comment: It might be that you use a different display (even if you have only one!). So type "echo $DISPLAY" first, it will tell your display number that you should add as described above.

Comment: Please also note that the command above works for gedit, but for some strange (to me, at least) reason, it does not work for libreoffice. There, you have to eliminate these two ampersand symbols! (Took me >60 minutes to find that error^^).

Comment: Also, it greatly helps to append the following command (after a blank) right at the end of your cron job:  >> /home/USERNAME/Desktop/log 2>&1 which will append all outputs (errors/logs). Add it until it works!